# Unable to see browser(Firefox/chrome/IE) in Monitoring tool (AppDynamics) when load is running from Load Runner(Http/Https protocol)

Tags: loadrunner

I'm new in LoadRunner. My problem is:

When I'm running the script from LoadRunner (Http/Https protocol), I'm unable to see the browserName(like firefox, Chrome, IE etc)  in monitoring tool (AppDynamics).

But when I'm running script from LoadRunner (using truClient protocol), I'm able to see the browserName in AppDynamics.

My Objective is to see the browser Name in AppDynamics Monitoring tool when I'm using HTTP/HTTPS protocol.

**

- *What I did from my end:*

**

I have compared both the header when script was running from    different protocol using Fiddler, Burp-Suite. (No difference)
User-Agent string is common in both the protocol.

Can someone suggest/help me on this? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** 
Version of LoadRunner is 12.60.
Just running with one transaction i.e launching the home page only from both the protocol.

Please let me know if you need more information from my end.

Comment: Architecture is a foundation skill for performance testers.  This is a question on client architecture.  This is an opportunity to revisit this skill set with your performance testing mentor

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see the browser name in HTTP protocol is because there is no browser. The protocol is a transport level protocol which means it simulates the traffic of the browser without running the actual browser. This allows the protocol to simulate many more virtual users than a client level protocol such as TruClient.

EDIT: There is no dedicated API and you must use the user agent. Please refer to this article for more details: https://www.appdynamics.com/blog/engineering/how-to-use-appdynamics-with-loadrunner-for-load-testing/

Comment: Can you please suggest me some API name that I can use , so that app dynamics will show the Browser_Name (firefox/chrome)  at monitoring side window. If possible please share the configuration part also like where I have to configure the API (LR SIDE or APPDYNAMICS side)

Comment: @Manish Sorry, I confused AppDynamics with a different tool. For AppDynamics setting the user agent in the runtime settings should be enough

Comment: Then the client is probably doing something else. You need to figure out what additional steps are needed.

Comment: Record all headers.  AppD is likely adding an add-in specific header.  Without that addition AppD doesn't understand the source dataflow.   I would recommend marking this as a "LoadRunner HTTP User" and not a specific browser to avoid confusion in your data sets